# Entity Framework getting Branches table throws an exception from the type Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException I don't know why

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework in ASP.NET Core Web API project
I have built the model using the scaffold command from the package manager console and everything is working properly, I can edit the tables, I can insert data, I can update, get lists of data using many different criteria.
any ways my problem is when I try to get all the data from a table named 'Branches'
I get an error of type Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException with a message says "Invalid column name 'UserIndx'."

**this is my code that tries to get the data**

```
/// <summary>
/// Function that returns a list with all the branch table data.
/// </summary>
public List<Branch> getBranches()
{
    List<Branch> list = new List<Branch>();
    try
    {
        list = db.Branches.ToList();
        return list;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        er.writeToErrorLog("BLDataEntry", "Branches", "getBranches", ex);
        return list;
    }
}
```

This is my branch class that was auto generated by the scaffold command

```
public partial class Branch
{
    public int Indx { get; set; }
    public string Branch1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? IataNo { get; set; }
    public int? VatDealer { get; set; }
    public string? Tel { get; set; }
    public string? Tel2 { get; set; }
    public string? Fax { get; set; }
    public string? Fax2 { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public int? SagentId { get; set; }
    public int? OutAccGroup { get; set; }
    public int? IntAccGroup { get; set; }
    public int? IncAccGroup { get; set; }
    public int? IspAccGroup { get; set; }
    public byte[]? RptLogo { get; set; }
    public byte[]? AppLogo { get; set; }
    public int? Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public bool SellOnly { get; set; }
    public bool? IsOblClientDetails { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
    public string? LocalName { get; set; }
    public string? LocalAddress { get; set; }
    public string? Longitude { get; set; }
    public string? Latitude { get; set; }
    public string? WorkingDaysHours { get; set; }
    public string? Iban { get; set; }
    public string? KvKnr { get; set; }
    public string? Btwnr { get; set; }
    public string? Biccode { get; set; }
    public byte[]? AddLogos { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? WebSite { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccBank> AccBanks { get; } = new List<AccBank>();
    public virtual ICollection<Agent> Agents { get; } = new List<Agent>();
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; } = new List<Department>();
    public virtual ICollection<SpecialProductDistribution> SpecialProductDistributions { get; } = new List<SpecialProductDistribution>();
}
```

This is the code from the dbContext.cs that also was auto generated by the scaffold command by entity framework

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Indx);

    entity.Property(e => e.AddLogos).HasColumnType("image");
    entity.Property(e => e.Address).HasMaxLength(50);
    entity.Property(e => e.AppLogo).HasColumnType("image");
    entity.Property(e => e.Biccode)
        .HasMaxLength(10)
        .HasColumnName("BICcode");
    entity.Property(e => e.Branch1)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasColumnName("Branch");
    entity.Property(e => e.Btwnr)
        .HasMaxLength(15)
        .HasColumnName("BTWnr");
    entity.Property(e => e.CloseDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
    entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(100);
    entity.Property(e => e.Fax).HasMaxLength(15);
    entity.Property(e => e.Fax2).HasMaxLength(15);
    entity.Property(e => e.IataNo).HasMaxLength(12);
    entity.Property(e => e.Iban)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasColumnName("IBAN");
    entity.Property(e => e.IsOblClientDetails)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
    entity.Property(e => e.KvKnr)
        .HasMaxLength(15)
        .HasColumnName("KvKNr");
    entity.Property(e => e.Latitude)
        .HasMaxLength(15)
        .HasColumnName("latitude");
    entity.Property(e => e.LocalAddress).HasMaxLength(100);
    entity.Property(e => e.LocalName).HasMaxLength(100);
    entity.Property(e => e.Longitude)
        .HasMaxLength(15)
        .HasColumnName("longitude");
    entity.Property(e => e.OpenDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
        .HasColumnType("datetime");
    entity.Property(e => e.RptLogo).HasColumnType("image");
    entity.Property(e => e.SagentId).HasColumnName("SAgentID");
    entity.Property(e => e.Tel).HasMaxLength(15);
    entity.Property(e => e.Tel2).HasMaxLength(15);
    entity.Property(e => e.WebSite).HasMaxLength(100);
    entity.Property(e => e.WorkingDaysHours).HasMaxLength(255);
});
```

I have searched the whole project for a column with the name UserIndx and it doesn't exist in my whole solution I have tried to pull a specific column from that table and it worked right as it should
the problem is basically when I wanna grab all the table into a list.

I have tried getting back data when I asked for specific columns.

Comment: Please don't post exception message as an image.

Comment: i just keep getting this error randomly on different tables too